# Reset current exception chain

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code in my app:

```
try:
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
except Exception:
    logger.warning('Failed to render the custom %s page', exc.code, exc_info=True)
```

When my MongoDB is down, I have this:

```
18:44:55 WARNING Failed to render the custom 500 page
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
  File ".../venv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pymongo/topology.py", line 189, in select_servers
    self._error_message(selector))
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 61] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
...
pymongo.errors.ServerSelectionTimeoutError: localhost:27017: [Errno 61] Connection refused
```

I don't want info about the first exception -- I already logged it my code before. I want only exception which happens inside the try/except block to be logged (the one which is shown after "During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:").

How can I reset current exception chain before the try/except block?

I could try:

```
try:
    ...
except Exception as exc:
    exc.__cause__ = None
    logger.exception(...)
```

But it would spoil the useful chain of several exceptions which might have happened inside try/except.

Comment: not sure if this is the appropriated fix, but have you tried using just `except` instead of `except Exception`?

Comment: @JeandersonBarrosCândido: that would not make any difference here. You generally don't want to use a blanket `except:` anyway.

Comment: So what part of the exception did you want to log? The first section, or the second part below *during handling of the above*?

Comment: So when is a chain useful, and when isn't the chain useful? Reset only that part of the chain you don't find useful by clearing the `__cause__`.

Comment: @warvariuc: yes, hence my question on what constitutes something you would not want to  spoil.

Comment: I want to remove from the chain all exceptions that happened before entering the try/except block. If inside try/except several exceptions happened in a chain -- I want that chain to be kept.